# Is there any way of explaining the Cayley/Beltrami–Klein metric to undergrads?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, norms, quadrics

How to explain the Cayley-Klein or sometimes called Beltrami–Klein metric concept to find the distance between two points in a hyperbolic space to an audience with no higher education than maybe a postgrad? What are a, b, C and what are p, q on quadric Q.

${\displaystyle d(a,b)=C\log {\frac {\left|bp\right|\left|qa\right|}{\left|ap\right|\left|qb\right|}}}$

Furthermore, is there any exercises online in finding distance using the above concept?

Comment: Material for a second-year undergrad is not research-level mathematics, so this question is off-topic here. It would be on-topic at Math Educators Stack Exchange, though that community (or any other) might expect a bit more work and information from the poster.

Comment: I see the phrase “second-year undergrad” has now been replaced with “postgrad” in the main text, but the title is still about undergrads, and it still looks like “help — I don’t understand the Wikipedia article!” is the subtext for the question.

Comment: @MattF. I posted it on other stack exchanges but no answer. Can you answer?

Comment: Please provide links to other posts. Contributors might be willing to answer there, but answering off-topic questions is considered inappropriate.